# How to switch Elastic IP from one EC2 instance to another using cloudformation?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation

I am associating an elastic IP to an EC2 instance that i am creating via cloudformation. I am attaching it to my EC2 instance via

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: 2010-09-09
Description:
  Testing stuff

Resources:
  myENI:
    Type: AWS::EC2::NetworkInterface
    Properties:
      SubnetId: <subnet-id>
  Instance:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Instance
    Properties:
      ImageId: <ami-id>
      InstanceType: t2.micro
      NetworkInterfaces:
        - NetworkInterfaceId: !Ref myENI
          DeviceIndex: '0'
      Tags:
        - Key: Name
          Value: test-instance-1
  myEIP:
    Type: AWS::EC2::EIP
    Properties:
      Domain: vpc
  EIPAssociation:
    Type: AWS::EC2::EIPAssociation
    Properties:
      AllocationId: !GetAtt myEIP.AllocationId
      NetworkInterfaceId: !Ref myENI
    DependsOn: Instance
```

and i am creating the stack using `aws cloudformation create-stack --stack-name ec2-example --template-body file://test-instance.yaml`

Which creates my resources including the elastic IP. `35.82.18.137`, an instance, EIPAssociation and it's own ENI.

Now i spin up another EC2 instance by updating my existing stack by changing the value of tags to test-instance-2 using the following command `aws cloudformation create-stack --stack-name ec2-example-1 --template-body file://test-instance.yaml`

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: 2010-09-09
Description:
  Testing stuff

Resources:
  myENI:
    Type: AWS::EC2::NetworkInterface
    Properties:
      SubnetId: <subnet-id>
  Instance:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Instance
    Properties:
      ImageId: <ami-id>
      InstanceType: t2.micro
      NetworkInterfaces:
        - NetworkInterfaceId: !Ref myENI
          DeviceIndex: '0'
      Tags:
        - Key: Name
          Value: test-instance-2
  myEIP:
    Type: AWS::EC2::EIP
    Properties:
      Domain: vpc
  EIPAssociation:
    Type: AWS::EC2::EIPAssociation
    Properties:
      AllocationId: !GetAtt myEIP.AllocationId
      NetworkInterfaceId: !Ref myENI
    DependsOn: Instance
```

Which creates a new instance and issues a new EIP : `44.229.115.61`, an instance, EIPAssociation and it's own ENI.

How can i switch over the old elastic IP `35.82.18.137` from the old instance to the new instance without deleting the old instance? Is that even possible using cloudformation ( No clickops if possible )?

Comment: Are they in the same template? Just change the EIPAssociation to use the new instance?

Comment: Yes paulo. you are correct. they are in the same template. I'll give that a try. thank you.

Comment: Cool, let me know

Comment: @Paolo I have updated the question. Turns out there was a bit more to it than i initially started with. Can you please take a look. Thank you.

Comment: So the only thing changing is the tags? Are you sure that spins up a new instance? How are you deploying the updated stack?

Comment: @Paolo Whoops. I'll update the question.

Comment: Basically i'm creating a new instance using `aws cloudformation create-stack --stack-name ec2-example-1 --template-body file://test-instance.yaml`

Comment: It sounds like want to update the stack instead of creating a new one.. you should use [update-stack](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/cloudformation/update-stack.html)

Comment: No, i'm afraid i have to create a new instance and switchover the elastic IP.

Comment: Don't forget to upvote if you found the answer useful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible as outlined in the documentation: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/refactor-stacks.html

Here's a demo (all of the code snippets below are run in `bash`).

---

Let's say we have these two templates (note that the first template **must** have the deletion policy set to `Retain` for the EIP):

*template1.yml* :

```yaml
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: 2010-09-09
Description:
  Testing stuff

Resources:
  myENI:
    Type: AWS::EC2::NetworkInterface
    Properties:
      SubnetId: <subnet-id>
  Instance:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Instance
    Properties:
      ImageId: ami-02d7ab1717c7787ce
      InstanceType: t2.micro
      NetworkInterfaces:
        - NetworkInterfaceId: !Ref myENI
          DeviceIndex: '0'
      Tags:
        - Key: Name
          Value: test-instance-1
  myEIP:
    Type: AWS::EC2::EIP
    DeletionPolicy: Retain
    Properties:
      Domain: vpc
  EIPAssociation:
    Type: AWS::EC2::EIPAssociation
    Properties:
      AllocationId: !GetAtt myEIP.AllocationId
      NetworkInterfaceId: !Ref myENI
    DependsOn: Instance
```

*template2.yml*:

```yaml
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: 2010-09-09
Description:
  Testing stuff

Resources:
  myENI:
    Type: AWS::EC2::NetworkInterface
    Properties:
      SubnetId: <subnet-id>
  Instance:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Instance
    Properties:
      ImageId: ami-02d7ab1717c7787ce
      InstanceType: t2.micro
      NetworkInterfaces:
        - NetworkInterfaceId: !Ref myENI
          DeviceIndex: '0'
      Tags:
        - Key: Name
          Value: test-instance-2
```

then let's deploy them both:

```bash
$ aws cloudformation deploy --template-file template1.yml --stack-name stack1
$ aws cloudformation deploy --template-file template2.yml --stack-name stack2
```

once the stacks have been deployed, we need to fetch the allocation id and the public ip of the elastic ip deployed in the first stack:

```bash
$ EIP_PHYSICAL_RESOURCE_ID=$(aws cloudformation describe-stack-resources --stack-name stack1 --query 'StackResources[?LogicalResourceId == `myEIP`].PhysicalResourceId' --output text)
$ EIP_ALLOCATION_ID=$(aws ec2 describe-addresses --query "Addresses[?PublicIp == '${EIP_PHYSICAL_RESOURCE_ID}'].AllocationId" --output text)
```

we can now proceed to remove the EIP and the EIP association from the first stack:

*template1.yml*

```yaml
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: 2010-09-09
Description:
  Testing stuff

Resources:
  myENI:
    Type: AWS::EC2::NetworkInterface
    Properties:
      SubnetId: <subnet-id>
  Instance:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Instance
    Properties:
      ImageId: ami-02d7ab1717c7787ce
      InstanceType: t2.micro
      NetworkInterfaces:
        - NetworkInterfaceId: !Ref myENI
          DeviceIndex: '0'
      Tags:
        - Key: Name
          Value: test-instance-1
```

and let's update the first stack:

```bash
$ aws cloudformation update-stack --template-body file://template1.yml --stack-name stack1
```

now we must modify the second template to include the EIP.

*template2.yml*:

```yaml
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: 2010-09-09
Description:
  Testing stuff

Resources:
  myENI:
    Type: AWS::EC2::NetworkInterface
    Properties:
      SubnetId: <subnet-id>
  Instance:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Instance
    Properties:
      ImageId: ami-02d7ab1717c7787ce
      InstanceType: t2.micro
      NetworkInterfaces:
        - NetworkInterfaceId: !Ref myENI
          DeviceIndex: '0'
      Tags:
        - Key: Name
          Value: test-instance-2
  myEIP:
    Type: AWS::EC2::EIP
    DeletionPolicy: Retain
    Properties:
      Domain: vpc
```

now let's create the following file (`file.txt`) which will be used in the import operation later:

```json
[
  {
      "ResourceType":"AWS::EC2::EIP",
      "LogicalResourceId":"myEIP",
      "ResourceIdentifier": {
        "AllocationId": "$EIP_ALLOCATION_ID",
        "PublicIp": "$EIP_PHYSICAL_RESOURCE_ID"
      }
  }
]
```

and now let's populate it (`envsubst` is a handy way to replace the two variables into the text file, however you can obviously do this in other ways too):

```bash
$ export EIP_PHYSICAL_RESOURCE_ID
$ export EIP_ALLOCATION_ID
$ envsubst < file.txt > resourcesToImport.txt
```

`resourcesToImport.txt` now contains the allocation id and public ip of the EIP.
Let's run the import operation:

```bash
$ aws cloudformation create-change-set \
    --stack-name stack2 --change-set-name ImportChangeSet \
    --change-set-type IMPORT \
    --resources-to-import file://resourcesToImport.txt \
    --template-body file://template2.yml
$ aws cloudformation execute-change-set --change-set-name ImportChangeSet --stack-name stack2
```

the second stack now has imported the EIP.

Finally, let's create an association with the existing instance

*template2.yml*:

```yaml
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: 2010-09-09
Description:
  Testing stuff

Resources:
  myENI:
    Type: AWS::EC2::NetworkInterface
    Properties:
      SubnetId: <subnet-id>
  Instance:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Instance
    Properties:
      ImageId: ami-02d7ab1717c7787ce
      InstanceType: t2.micro
      NetworkInterfaces:
        - NetworkInterfaceId: !Ref myENI
          DeviceIndex: '0'
      Tags:
        - Key: Name
          Value: test-instance-2
  myEIP:
    Type: AWS::EC2::EIP
    DeletionPolicy: Retain
    Properties:
      Domain: vpc
  EIPAssociation:
    Type: AWS::EC2::EIPAssociation
    Properties:
      AllocationId: !GetAtt myEIP.AllocationId
      NetworkInterfaceId: !Ref myENI
    DependsOn: Instance
```

and let's update the stack:

```bash
$ aws cloudformation update-stack --template-body file://template2.yml --stack-name stack2
```

The EIP which was originally associated with the instance in the first stack is now associated with the instance in the second stack

Answer (score -1):

You need to tag each IP instance first, and then switch them in the Cloudformation template:

1. Create an Elastic IP:
   [image]
2. Develop the full deployment template:
   [image]

More details (actually, a tutorial with more explanations) is [available at this link](https://medium.com/cloud-security/deploying-an-aws-elastic-ip-address-dbcca9b237ba).